# Drupal 7: check login password with DB password

Tags: 7, users

I'm working on drupal 7, i'm looking for developing customize user log-in module into my site. but facing a problem in that, when we are submit log-in page then password doesn't match with DB password. because drupal not using MD5 encryption method for storing password into it.

So what would be the batter solution for it? how can i achieve my task without fail.?
Please help me, its appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you customizing your user log-in? Is it just a new look? It is hard to know without knowing what your module is doing, or planning to do. Is your module just changing the theme? The form(s)? Or are you trying to completely implement a new login mechanism from scratch and trying to integrate it with Drupal?

Comment: yes exactly.i'm trying to implement it from the scratch..

Comment: is it possible to customize in existing module for different use?

Comment: Take a look at the Drupal 7 core module called user.module.  It is located in your drupal directory under modules/user.  
Check out line 2182. There is a function called function user_authenticate($name, $password).  That should point you in the right direction, I think.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to customize the existing user login module.  You need to take a look at the hook_form_alter().  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Using the hook_form_alter() will allow you to add/overwrite/remove fields.  It is very powerful and can be used anywhere on your Drupal website wherever there are forms.  You could create a new look or add different messages or notes on multiple login pages using hook_form_alter().

Comment: Bad idea to change user.module. Create another module instead. Why do you need to re-write authentication from scratch?

Comment: The question is about validating against something else than the built in password mechanism. The poster is not asking about theming (changing the layout/design).

Comment: BetaRide: Since English is not the original poster's native language, I assumed that he might have meant he wanted to do some visual validation that could go along with some other validation methods.  I don't know the entire scope of what he wants so asking for more clarification is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Paul-m: you are correct.  But just to clarify, I never told him to alter the core user.module.  I said for him to TAKE A LOOK at the user.module, specifically at line 2182. From there, he can then use that to write his custom module

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak the existing user login form by implementing [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or one of its friends (see link). It allows you to add your own password validation functions.

If you don't know which form ID to use, you can add this code to a custom module to get all used form ids printed out:

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    dpm($form_id);
}
```

You need the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, and appropriate permissions to see the output of `dpm()`.

But there's more. You have to think about password changes, password retrieval, account creation, etc. To let users log in (with your own password check) you need to have a valid Drupal user account for every user. It's not enough to just validate the password against your own database. A possibility would be creating the user accounts in the background once the password check was positive.

A completely different approach: Import your existing users into the Drupal users table, and let them know they have to go through password retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 doesn't store the MD5, but the password's hash.

You can compare the passwords pretty easily: Use [user_hash_password()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7) to get the corresponding hash of the entered password. The function is found inside includes/password.inc.

You can do the comparison in a custom module through a validation handler for the user login form.

Comment: The first sentence doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

To compare the passwords you could try [`user_check_password()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_check_password/7).

> Check whether a plain text password matches a stored hashed password.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **$password**: A plain-text password
>
> **$account**: A user object with at least the fields from the {users} table.
>
> **Return value**
>
> TRUE or FALSE.

See also [Secure password hashing functions for user authentication](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/7).